# Most efficient way to store "likes" like Facebook and Stackoverflow

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

What would be the best way to store "likes" or "upvotes" in a mysql database?

Here was what I was thinking:

```
likes (table)
    id (auto increment)
    post_id
    user_id
```

but would the `likes` table have millions or even billions of rows since each person that would like a post would insert into 1 row and each person can like more than one time and there's more than one user.

how does facebook or stackoverflow manage to do this in a database? any links or guides is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Too broad and likely to attract opinionated answers. Please ask more specific questions on SO.

Comment: There is no intrinsic problem with having millions of rows in this table.  But you may also want a denormalised column in your posts table to cache the resulting "score" of all the votes combined (so you don't have to calculate it each time).

Answer (score 5):

Don't you need a column for up- versus down-vote?

Get rid of the id; instead, use `PRIMARY KEY(post_id, user_id)`.

By having the `post_id` first, you can find all the votes for a given post effiently.  Meanwhile the list of all votes for a user_id is less efficient.  If you need that, then also have `INDEX(user_id)`

Comment: What would getting rid of the `id` do and what does primary key do?

Comment: @packnob890 removing the id column saves 1/3 of the data storage required.  The primary key option allows you to say that a row is uniquely identified by the combination of two columns, and so also enforce uniqueness on the combination of those two columns.

Comment: @packnob890 - and, in InnoDB, the data is clustered with the PK.  So, once it looks up the PK, the data is right there; no extra step.

Answer (score -2):

store a string (or json) with comma separated id's of users. 
No need for an extra table, just add it as a column to the Post.
An extra column could be used for the total number (count) of likes.

Comment: Comma separated values as a string in a single field is a SQL anti pattern and code smell.  It breaches the atomic nature of the field

Comment: @MatBailie  There is a even a json column in more modern databases like Postgres or mariaDB (mysql is planning this also) if you want to stick to what a DB system provides. If you take a look a level deeper at what a json or csv is really like in the database you'll see that there isn't much difference between the two.  Overnormalisation is the antipattern here, imho.

Comment: JSON data types, arrays, structures, etc, that are natively supported by the RDBMS preserve strong data type enforcement, enable indexing and constraints, etc, etc.  Mimicking it with strings and arbitrary separators introduces a long list of potential failures, debuging difficulty, perfirmance overheads and maintenance costs.  From an engineering point of view it should be a last resort and not a first choice.